# Certificate storage in Firefox 3.6.x removed when updated to Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, firefox-3.6

Where do (/did) Mozilla Firefox store my certificates on Mac OS X (10.6.7)?

I've updated Firefox to 4, and I couldn't backup my certificates in FF3.6.1 and I thought to myself that Firefox probably would migrate my certificates to the new version. Well, that didn't happen... So I'm currently locked out from my electronic ID. Is there a way to restore my certs?